# Should we use savedInstanceState in fragments if there are getArguments()?

Tags: android, android-fragments, onsaveinstancestate

In Android fragments we can get initial data in `onCreate()` from `savedInstanceState` or `getArguments()`. I often check them both for `null` and then assign variables. For instance, in Kotlin:

```
val bundle = savedInstanceState ?: arguments
bundle?.let {
    startDate = Date(it.getLong(ARG_START_DATE, 0))
    endDate = Date(it.getLong(ARG_END_DATE, startDate.time))
}
```

So, first I check whether `savedInstanceState != null` and if so, will get data from there. If it is `null`, I will check `getArguments() != null` and if so will get data from there. Otherwise variables will be `null`, `0` or `false`.

When we leave a fragment and call `onSaveInstanceState()` we can write data to a bundle and later can read them in `onCreate()`. But we can also write data to `getArguments()` and read them from any place of the fragment. Why should we use `savedInstanceState` as we can write to `getArguments()`?

Comment: What you're trying to do? I mean you need to read the parameters from Arguments when the Fragment is attached or you want to save the state of the Fragment when configuration changes happened?

Comment: @MrVasilev, I want to save and restore data after screen rotation and in other cases: when the `Fragment` is first created, when it is resumed and gets data from another `Fragment`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The main difference between these two options is their storage location.The arguments are stored in memory but The saveInstanceState is serialized to disk.
You should look at this page:
https://developer.android.com/topic/libraries/architecture/saving-states

Answer (score 2):

setting and getting argument is really doesn't do anything about `savedInstanceState`, when you call a `Fragment` you can set a `Bundle` to it and when you are in the `Fragment` you can get what you sent to the `Fragment` using `getArgument`. `savedInstanceState` is normally used when you don't want to loose data when configuration changes, like rotation of the device.

Comment: I mean, we can write to `getArguments()` everywhere in the `Fragment`. If configuration changes, we can write to `getArguemnts()` instead of `savedInstanceState` too. So, in all cases we can write to and read from `getArguments()`. They are multipurpose and accessible from any event of the `Fragment`.

Comment: Exactly, but with savedInstanceState you also saved other things as well.

Comment: It's interesting. If you don't mind, can you explain a bit?

Comment: you know sometimes things happens that are unexpected, for example, in one my projects whenever the configuration changes, the menu inflation runs again and my menu with 2 menu item turned into a menu with 4 items, I solve these kind of problems with savedInstanceState.

Comment: Thanks, you are right, I forgot about that problem. We should save to `savedInstanceState` in `onSaveInstanceState()` and later analyze it in `onCreateView()` in order to check whether confuguration has changed or not. Please, update the answer with this idea so that I could accept it.

Answer (score 0):

As *@SinaMN75* said, when a fragment is created, it can check whether it restores after configuration change or is initialized for the first time. After screen rotation some difficulties can happen, for instance, duplication of menu items, change of the `Toolbar` title. In this case in `onCreate()` we should check `savedInstanceState != null` and read data from there. `getArguments()` won't give us the information about configuration change.

Of course, we should override `onSaveInstanceState()` in order to save needed variables.